# In Android UIAutomator, how to copy files from sdcard to some other location like data/local/tmp?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

My UIAutomator testcase requires a file to be copied from sdcard to data/local/tmp and proceed further. When I use the below mentioned code:

```
public void RunAsRoot(String cmds) throws IOException{
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmds");
}
```

I get this exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [cmds] Working Directory: null Environment: null
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:241)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
    ... 20 more
```

Is there any other way to do the same? I appreciate the answers, 
Thanks.

Comment: I actually missed what "cmds" is here.It is a string variable holding the command "cat mnt/sdcard/Input.txt >> data/local/tmp/Input.txt"

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your example. "cmds" instead of cmds. This code is part of an Android app? What kind of commands exactly are you using? Are you launching on a rooted phone or an emulator?

Comment: I am running this code in uiAutomator test case which is not inside app. Java code is built into a JAR file and is run using the adb shell commands. I 'm  not trying on a rooted phone.